# How to pipe Writable Buffer to a ReadStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I take a writable stream and return a readable stream from a buffer?

I have the following to write the data that comes from an ftp server to an array of chunks:

```
let chunks = []
let writable = new Writable
writable._write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
  chunks.push(chunk)
  callback()
}
```

I am then creating a new readstream:

```
let readable = new ReadStream()
```

I then tried to pipe the writable to the readable but that doesn't seem to work:

> Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'.

```
writable.pipe(readable)
```

Here is the entire method:

```
export class FTP {
  readStream(filePath, options = {}) {
    let conn = this.getConnection(this.name)
    if (!conn) return Buffer.from('')
    filePath = this.forceRoot(filePath) 
    let chunks = []
    let writable = new Writable
    writable._write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
      chunks.push(chunk)
      callback()
    }
    let readable = new ReadStream()

    conn.client.download(writable, filePath, options.start || undefined)
    writable.pipe(readable)
    return readable
  }
}
```

I then read from the stream and pipe the output to the response object created from `http.createServer()` like this:

```
      let stream = store.readStream(file, { start, end })
        .on('open', () => stream.pipe(res))
        .on('close', () => res.end())
        .on('error', err => res.end(err))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, Node.js streams are hard to grasp. Logically, you don't need two streams here. If you want to read from your FTP class as from a stream, you just need to implement a single readable stream. Check [this section](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream) of the docs out to have an idea how to implement a readable stream from scratch:

```
class SourceWrapper extends Readable {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);

    this._source = getLowLevelSourceObject();

    // Every time there's data, push it into the internal buffer.
    this._source.ondata = (chunk) => {
      // If push() returns false, then stop reading from source.
      if (!this.push(chunk))
        this._source.readStop();
    };

    // When the source ends, push the EOF-signaling `null` chunk.
    this._source.onend = () => {
      this.push(null);
    };
  }
  // _read() will be called when the stream wants to pull more data in.
  // The advisory size argument is ignored in this case.
  _read(size) {
    this._source.readStart();
  }
}
```

However, from your example, I can conclude, that `conn.client.download()` expects a writable stream as an input parameter. In such case you just can take a standard [PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream which is a duplex (i.e. writable on the left and readable on the right side) stream with no transformation applied:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');

export class FTP {
  readStream(filePath, options = {}) {
    let conn = this.getConnection(this.name);
    if (!conn) return Buffer.from('');
    filePath = this.forceRoot(filePath);
    
    const pt = new PassThrough();
    conn.client.download(pt, filePath, options.start);
    return pt;
  }
}
```

You can find more information on Node.js streams [here](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/nodejs-readable-streams-distilled/) and [here](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/nodejs-writable-streams-distilled/).

**UPD:** Usage example:

```
// assume res is an [express or similar] response object.
const s = store.readStream(file, { start, end });
s.pipe(res);
```

Comment: My method needs to return a `ReadStream` because I need access to `.on('open', () => stream.pipe(res))` will this allow for that?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes, since `PassThrough` extends `Transform` which extends `Duplex` which "extends" both `Readable` and `Writable`

Comment: `Type 'PassThrough' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadStream': close, bytesRead, path`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn do you use TypeScript?

Comment: Yeah I am using typescript

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it's not clear from your snippet. And then we need more details on the actual compilation error.

Comment: Okay, I have added an extra piece of information to the question, I hope it helps.

Comment: You didn't add the actual compilation error. However, from your extra snippet, I see that you're misusing pipe feature. When you pipe a readable stream into a writable stream, you don't need to care about a low-level stream protocol (opening, closing, etc). It's done for your by the stream pipeline under the hood.

Comment: I figured out how to send the data from the passthrough to the client: `let stream = store.readStream(file, { start, end })
        .on('data', chunk => res.write(chunk))
        .on('end', () => res.end())`

Comment: No, it's a wrong way to go. Writing to a writable stream without checking the return value of write method leads to memory overconsumption.

Comment: @IvanVelichko What do you mean? Could you please explain what you mean by changing the the return value?

Comment: Please read this https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe works the other way round as you're thinking. According to [Node.js's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options), `pipe()` is a method of `Readable`, and it accepts a `Writable` as its destination. What you were trying to do was pipe a `Writable` to a `Readable`, but actually it's a `Readable` that can be piped to a `Writeable`, not the other way round.

Try passing a `PassThrough` to `download()` and return that same `PassThrough`?